# Why is there a special site dedicated for Arduino, and not for uC/Embedded stuff?

Tags: discussion, site-proposal

I don't know if it is a right place to ask, but why isn't a certain low level programming site for embedded systems in the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe because there's not enough need for it? *Programming* questions about embedded systems are on-topic for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/); if you have a hardware-related question, there's [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) for you.

The same could be said for Arduino, but they managed to get enough support to found their own community on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58150/arduino). A proposal for general embedded systems has been tried [two](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70800/embedded-systems) [times](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-systems), but failed due to the lack of interest.

Comment: I didn't knew about Stack Overflow support for the embedded system programming. It looked to me that it was in the electrical Engineering section and it seemed all messed up